# Read buffer from keyboard in Assembly

Tags: assembly, buffer, dos, dosbox, x86-16

I need to read string from a keyboard with a buffer.

With some help of examples and literature, I managed to write this code, but when I try to print out the string that I've inserted, it just gives me message "Input your string again:".

What should I change in my code, in order to get printed what I've inserted?

```
.model small

stack 100h

.data

    ;reading buffer
    buffSize DB 255       ;Number of maximum characters than can be read
    read DB ?             ;Number of characters that was read
    buffer  DB 255 dup (?) ;Read characters are placed here

    ;Other data
    input DB "Input your string: $",13,10
.code

Start:

    MOV ax,@data
    MOV ds,ax

    MOV ah,9
    MOV dx, OFFSET input
    INT 21h                     ;Prints input string

    MOV ah, 0Ah
    MOV dx, OFFSET buffSize
    INT 21h                     ;Text is read

    MOV bx, OFFSET buffer       ;Address of buffer is inserted to bx
    MOV cl, read                ;Content of read is inserted to cl
    MOV ch, 0                   ;In cl there is a number of inserted characters

    MOV byte ptr [ds:bx], '$'

    MOV ah, 9
    MOV dx, OFFSET buffer
    INT 21h

    MOV ah,4Ch
    INT 21h
END Start
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste actual code into your question, or did you manually rewrite it? As is, it may even not compile, the line `reading buffer` looks to be meant as comment, and `nextLine` doesn't work the way you have it. If you are using dosbox, you have very likely the .asm file mapped from your host OS somewhere, so just open it in text editor and copy/paste real source. Otherwise from what I see your code will print what you did enter. Not just that, but it should start with that, and continue onward till address `nextLine`, where it will find the `'$'` string terminator, ah=9 requires that.

Comment: I've manually rewrote it drom example, but not all the code. The whole code changes string's letters to lower case. I've tried just to read and print string. Reading buffer is a comment in my code, but I've accidentaly deleted in when editing text in this site. So what I understand, i should add a $ in my code? How can I do that? (In example it is shown that I can do this by writing this line MOV byte ptr [ds:bx], '$' but it didnt work. I've edited my code in the question)

Comment: bufSize is 255, but you reserve just 25 bytes (another typo? Or you don't understand the idea how rigid the assembly is, and how you must to reserve memory either in fixed way during compilation, or write (quite some) code to handle dynamic memory). When user enters: "ABC" and hits enter, you have in memory bytes `FF 03 41 42 43 0D ?? ?? ...` (or maybe `0A`, not sure, check in debugger, also re-check I got the entered length correctly, not sure if it's 3 or 4). You have to calculate address of that `<EOL>` (depends on the size of entered string), and then overwrite that char with `'$'`.

Comment: But that does apply only when you want to output the string through `int 21h, ah=9`, which expects strings `$` terminated. You can also output it char by char just going by the returned length, without adding any terminator, or you can write directly to video ram, not using the very slow BIOS/DOS interrupts at all, etc... there are many ways (possible definitions of calculations), how to achieve the same result (in your case the VGA memory at `B800:<somewhere>` will contain ASCII values of the letters, like `65` for `A` and their colour attributes, so the gfx card will draw the text.

Comment: Yeah it's mistake when rewriting, corrected that mistake. How could i calculate that address?

Comment: well, surprise, the memory is addressable by bytes, and each ASCII character is 1 byte, so `OFFSET buffer + 0` is address of first entered character, +1 is second, +2 is third... so basically you want to add entered length to address `buffer`. (and entered length is 8 bit, and address is 16 bit, so you need to zero-extend the length value to 16b for adding) ... SO is full of these questions, it's just not easy to find them (through SO search), try google.

Comment: Maybe you can give me a link to tutorial how could I print char by char? Can't really find...

Comment: If you are struggling with lot of terms I used in the hints, maybe drop strings and start with something easier, like doing simple arithmetic just over registers, without any output to screen. And just check the values of registers and memory in debugger. Then do some exercises on memory manipulation, how "array" can be done (several common ways), then get back to DOS "strings" ("arrays" of ASCII characters).

Comment: You should really copy/paste instead of retyping with errors.  at worst, `type foo.asm` to print it in a shell window, and then copy from there.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for asm tutorials and guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> input DB "Input your string: "
> nextLine db "$",13,10
> ```

The *nextLine* won't do much. Put the "$" **behind** the `13,10`.
Best also delimit the *input* text **on the same line**.

```
input    db "Input your string: $"
nextLine db 13,10,"$"
```

---

> ```
> buffSize DB 255       ;Number of maximum characters than can be read
> read DB ?             ;Number of characters that was read
> buffer  DB 25 dup (?) ;Read characters are placed here
> ```

If you allow for an input of 255 characters, you should also define a buffer large enough! `25 dup (?)` is much smaller than the stated size of 255.

---

To re-print the input, put a **$** behind the text:

```
mov  bx, OFFSET buffer     ;Start of the text
add  bl, read              ; plus the number of characters in the text
adc  bh, 0                 ;Maybe there was a carry from previous addition!
mov  byte ptr [bx], "$"    ;DOS needs string $-terminated
mov  ah, 09h               ;DOS.DisplayString
mov  dx, OFFSET buffer
int  21h
```

Comment: Thanks, edited my code, but the main problem is how to print string out..

Comment: It actually changes the word "Input..." into something that I write. For example, when I input "Hello", I get printed "Hello your string: Hello"

Comment: @DeividasBražėnas that's probably because you didn't fix your `nextLine`. Can you confirm you see in debugger damaged memory content? (not on screen, screen doesn't matter) ... you probably can't because you have no debugger. But that means you will waste days of time, because programming in assembly without debugger is like assembling robots blindfolded.

Comment: That's because you changed your mind and dropped the use of *nextLine*. With it, the program would have been fine!

Comment: I've got TASM with a debugger. I'll try then to get that nextLine again

Comment: Now it works! @Sep Roland maybe you can add comments to each line, please? It would help me a lot, as I'll understand it better. Thank you, mate!

Comment: You are my hero, lol! :D Its a little step for programmer, but a giant leap for me xD Maybe there's a way to get your contacts? For further questions, if you are ok with that. It would be really helpful, as I can post here just every 5 days.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155209/discussion-between-deividas-braznas-and-sep-roland).

Comment: You have a potential buffer overflow when add a "$" an the end of the string. Either increase the size (`buffer  DB 256 dup (?)`) to 256, or allow DOS to only use 254 (`buffSize DB 254`)

Comment: @Tommylee2k There's never any danger of buffer overflow! With the (maximum) setting of `buffSize DB 255` that the OP uses, DOS can return at most 254 characters __and__ a terminating carriage return. Since this carriage return is __not__ included in the returned count, the "$" character is written __on top of__ the carriage return, so staying well within the confines of the buffer.

Comment: @Fifoernik ah cool, never thought about that :) you're completely right

Answer (score 0):

You've put the '$' at the beginning of the buffer. Try

```
    mov di, cx
    mov [bx+di], '$'
```

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: In place of the mov [bx], '$'.